# Knowing $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_ny_n = 0$,try to prove $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n = 0$ or $\lim_{n\to\infty}y_n = 0$

Tags: limits

Knowing $$\lim_{n\to\infty}x_ny_n = 0$$try to prove $$\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n = 0$$or$$\lim_{n\to\infty}y_n = 0$$

Comment: Use proof by contradiction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to prove something that is not true.

Let $x_n=1$ if $n$ is odd and $x_n=\frac1{n}$ if $n$ is even.

Let $y_n=1$ if $n$ is even and $y_n=\frac1{n}$ if $n$ is odd.

Then $x_ny_n=\frac1{n}$ converges to $0$ but the sequences $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ do not converge.

Comment: How is it different from my example? :)

Comment: @KennyLau you allready preassumed that $(x_n)_n$ and $(y_n)_n$ would be convergent. Under that *extra* condition it can be shown that at least one of the sequences converges to $0$. My answer shows that the extra condition is not necessarily satisfied.

Answer (score 2):

Take $x_n = (n \mod 2)$ and $y_n = 1 - (n \mod 2)$.

---

If $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}x_n = A$ and $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}y_n = B$ with $A,B \ne 0$, then $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}x_ny_n = AB$ (why?), which is non-zero.

Comment: That's assuming both sequences converge. One should prove first that this is necessary (for at least one of them).

Comment: @GuidoA. my first paragraph already demonstrated why this is necessary.

Comment: I don't know if I'm missing something, but surely $\{x_n\}$ doesn't converge?

Comment: @paulw that's the point. It's a counter-example.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not seeing it as a direct consequence of what you've stated. Checking particular sequences doesn't prove the general result.

Comment: @GuidoA. It's a counter-example.

Comment: Oh right sorry for the silly comment, I should've reread the original question.

Comment: Whoops, my bad. You're totally right.